# User overwrite input.text value

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I got  this problem when trying to make an "edit" page for a profile stored in the database. 
To make it simple, I got a `textbox` where i get a value from the database and apply it to the textbox with textbooks. text = "value";`.

Works great this far. 
Then I want the user to be able to edit the text in the textbox and then press save, which should save the edited content of the textbox. But it doesn't, it saves the value i applied with textbox.text.
I get the value from the textbox in the button click function with textbox.text.

What am i doing wrong? - does the input from the user not overwrite the `.text value`?

```
    TextBoxNavn.Text = "Navn";       
   protected void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
       using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
           {
         command.Connection = connection;
         command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
         command.CommandText = "UPDATE Politikere SET Navn = @Navn WHERE ID = @ID";
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Navn", TextBoxNavn.Text);
           }
       }
```

Between the first line and the update statement, the user has edited the text in the textbox, but it still saves the value from the first line.

If i remove the first line and enter a value in the textbox it saves the entered value. That's why i suspect that the issue is the .text - but i don't know how else to do.`enter code here`

**EDIT**

Sorry if i am not clear. but all values are entered and works great. Too great for some. 
there's just too much code to point out small snippets for this. But by narrowing down the issue, I have found out that if i don't insert the database value with TextBoxNavn.Text in the page_load, it updates the value in the database with the new value. But when inserting it, user edited value does not get saved, but the value i inserted from the database does

**EDIT II**

The steps:

1. i get the data from the database and insert it into TextBoxNavn with TextBoxNavn.Text
2. The user will go to the page and edit the textbox, writing a new name in the TextBoxNavn
3. The user press "save" button
4. The value from the TextBoxNavn is retrieved by TextBoxNavn.Text
5. The value saved to the database is the value from step 1, but i need it to be the value from step 2

Comment: If you post your code it'll be easier for us to help you

Comment: you forget the pass @ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using DataBind() inside your page load. If yes please change it to`

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
DataBind();
}
```

`

or else share the complete code where you bind the data to your textbox. If you bind  your controls on PageLoad, Bind will be called before the control events and in that case the value you entered will be over ridden by the Databind() function. Pleae refer the following link for the asp.net page life cycle.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: In Page_Load i establish the connection to the database and make an array with the values from the database. Then i make the Textbox.text and when the save button is pressed i want to get the user edited text from the textbox. I don't use DataBind();

Comment: @Jonasnoerr have you passed `@ID` value??

Comment: Yes the UPDATE part is no problem. The ID works great too. The problem is that the user input does not overwrite the textbox.Text value